# DataTable columns not sorting properly

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have a column in a table which contains two numbers like header

Mean (standard deviation)
200 (156)

I have first two columns for area and area name which sorting fine. But mean (standard deviation) column for six months(column index 2 to 7) are not sorting as expected.

I have created a data table and rendered it but it's not sorting properly. Is there any way I can sort this kind of data. The code I use is as below. When I use type to "num" the sorting function doesn't work at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.table').DataTable( {
columnDefs: [
    {
        "type" : "html",
        "targets": [2,3,4,5,6,7],
        "className": 'dt-body-right',  
    }
],
"pageLength": 10
} );
```

});

Comment: You need to share what kind of data object you feed into the table, and explain why you use html column type for numbers. Anyway when adding data you can supply separate values for what to be displayed, what to use for sorting, etc. -- see the documenation for column sorting

Comment: I have an HTML table which I want to have some sorting and paging functionality and thus I am using DataTable. I have used before in so many projects and it's works fine if my columns contain only one value. For example in my current table if I Change value to be 200 (34) to 200  sorting will work fine. But I want to show both mean and stddev side by side in one column like 200(34).